# Error Installing 'util-linux-extra' failed during 'do-release-upgrade'

Tags: package-management, upgrade, dpkg, do-release-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from 22.04 to 23.04 using the `do-release-upgrade` command. Whenever I do so the command dumps me back into the shell without having changed my system at all.

`/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` (contents pasted below) tells me that a package by the name of `util-linux-extra:amd64` depends upon a version of `libsmartcols1:amd64` that can't be installed. But when I try to install the version it seems to want, apt can't seem to find it. And what I really can't understand is that the `util-linux-extra` package can't be installed either.

`sudo apt install libsmartcols1:amd64=2.38`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libsmartcols1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libsmartcols1:i386

E: Version '2.38' for 'libsmartcols1' was not found
```

I can't remember what I did exactly, but I broke something when I was screwing around trying to rollback my nvidia drivers for reasons I can no longer recall. My packages are obviously completely borked, and I am way out of my depth here trying to fix it. I would have reinstalled already but moving my docker containers and little Angular experiments seems like it would be a huge pain. Am I missing something obvious, or is it not worth trying to save and I should just do a clean install?

I have no held packages. `apt-mark showhold` returns nothing.

`sudo apt update` output:

```
Hit:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 https://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable InRelease
Hit:3 https://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release
Hit:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
Hit:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/agornostal/ulauncher/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

`sudo apt upgrade` and `sudo apt dist-upgrade` output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
#
# News about significant security updates, features and services will
# appear here to raise awareness and perhaps tease /r/Linux ;)
# Use 'pro config set apt_news=false' to hide this and future APT news.
#
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

`/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log` (ERROR on line 63)
https://pastebin.com/4eKb6BSF

`/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log`

```
Log time: 2023-09-21 23:57:43.490509
Log time: 2023-09-21 23:57:46.919395
Log time: 2023-09-21 23:58:34.013454
  MarkInstall xubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 < 2.248 @ii mK NPb IPb > FU=0
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on pipewire-pulse:amd64
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on snapd:amd64
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on wireplumber:amd64
  MarkInstall gnome-sudoku:amd64 < 1:42.0-1 @ii mK NPb IPb > FU=0
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on yelp:amd64
  MarkInstall gnome-software:amd64 < 41.5-2ubuntu2 @ii mK NPb IPb > FU=0
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on gnome-software-plugin-snap:amd64
  MarkInstall nvidia-driver-535:amd64 < 535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii mK NPb IPb > FU=0
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on libnvidia-decode-535:i386:any
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on libnvidia-encode-535:i386:any
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on libnvidia-fbc1-535:i386:any
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on libnvidia-gl-535:i386:any
  MarkInstall baobab:amd64 < 41.0-2 @ii mK NPb IPb > FU=0
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on yelp:amd64
  MarkInstall language-selector-gnome:amd64 < 0.219 @ii mK NPb IPb > FU=0
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on yelp:amd64
  MarkInstall gucharmap:amd64 < 1:14.0.3-1 @ii mK NPb IPb > FU=0
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on yelp:amd64
  MarkInstall xserver-xorg:amd64 < 1:7.7+23ubuntu2 @ii mK NPb IPb > FU=0
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on xserver-xorg-legacy:amd64
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64
  MarkInstall deluge-gtk:amd64 < 2.0.3-3.1 @ii mK NPb IPb > FU=0
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on python3-pygame:amd64
  MarkInstall gnome-mines:amd64 < 1:40.1-1 @ii mK NPb IPb > FU=0
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on yelp:amd64
  MarkInstall rhythmbox:amd64 < 3.4.4-5ubuntu1 @ii mK NPb IPb > FU=0
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on yelp:amd64
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on rhythmbox-plugins:amd64
  MarkInstall lightdm-gtk-greeter:amd64 < 2.0.8-2ubuntu1 @ii mK NPb IPb > FU=0
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on gnome-themes-standard:amd64
  MarkInstall wine64:amd64 < 6.0.3~repack-1 @ii mK NPb IPb > FU=0
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on wine32:amd64
  MarkInstall libreoffice-base-drivers:amd64 < 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii mK NPb IPb > FU=0
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb:amd64
  MarkInstall gnome-system-tools:amd64 < 3.0.0-9.1ubuntu1 @ii mK NPb IPb > FU=0
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on yelp:amd64
  MarkInstall xrdp:amd64 < 0.9.17-2ubuntu2 @ii mK NPb IPb > FU=0
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on xorgxrdp:amd64
  MarkInstall libc-dev-bin:amd64 < 2.35-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mK NPb IPb > FU=0
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on libc-devtools:amd64
  MarkInstall ubuntu-restricted-addons:amd64 < 26 @ii mK NPb IPb > FU=0
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3:amd64
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on gstreamer1.0-vaapi:amd64
  MarkInstall libreoffice-base:amd64 < 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii mK NPb IPb > FU=0
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on default-jre:amd64
  MarkInstall libreoffice-gtk3:amd64 < 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii mK NPb IPb > FU=0
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on gstreamer1.0-gtk3:amd64
  MarkInstall ure-java:amd64 < 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii mK NPb IPb > FU=0
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on default-jre:amd64
  MarkInstall inxi:amd64 < 3.3.13-1-1 @ii mK NPb IPb > FU=0
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on mesa-utils:amd64
  MarkInstall e2fsprogs:amd64 < 1.46.5-2ubuntu1.1 @ii mK NPb IPb > FU=0
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on e2fsprogs-l10n:amd64
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Done
Entering ResolveByKeep
  util-linux-extra:amd64 Depends on libsmartcols1:amd64 < 2.37.2-4ubuntu3 @ii mK > (>= 2.38) can't be satisfied!
nvidia-driver-535
Log time: 2023-09-21 23:58:40.881871
```